# Can't get jQuery closest to work

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't seem to get jquery closest to select the parent OL of my list items.

My code should effectively be saying if the list contains more than 8 LI's, apply a class name...but only apply a class name to the direct parent of the list containing more than 8 items.

Instead, it applies a class name to every OL in the document.

Code below:

```
    var boxFilters = jQuery('.items li');
    //check if there are 8 or more filters
    if (boxFilters.length > 8) {
        //if so add a class to the parent OL
        boxFilters.closest("ol").addClass("boxed");
    }
```

HTML

```
   <ol class="items">
      <li>1</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
   </ol>

   <ol class="items">
      <li>1</li>
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
      <li>5</li>
      <li>6</lI>
      <li>7</li>
      <li>8</li>
      <li>9</li>
   </ol>
```

Comment: Use `.closest()` as mentioned in title not `parents()`

Comment: Change `.ol` instead of  `ol`

Comment: can u share the html?

Comment: So why are you not selecting the lists and seeing how many lis they have. You are saying if the entire page has more than 8 lis, than add the class to all the parents up the tree from the li.

Comment: Apologies, I copied and pasted straight from a test I was doing where I was trying .parent instead. I've changed the sample and included an example of the HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the following approach:

```
$(".items").has("li:eq(7)").addClass("boxed");
```

This will check if the list `.items` has an 8th child element (7 because `:eq` is zero-based) and apply the class to it.

```js
$(".items").has("li:eq(7)").addClass("boxed");
```

```css
.boxed{
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol class="items">
  <li>Entry 1</li>
  <li>Entry 2</li>
  <li>Entry 3</li>
  <li>Entry 4</li>
  <li>Entry 5</li>
  <li>Entry 6</li>
  <li>Entry 7</li>
  <li>Entry 8</li>
</ol>
<ol class="items">
  <li>Entry 1</li>
  <li>Entry 2</li>
  <li>Entry 3</li>
</ol>
```

---

**References**

[.has()](https://api.jquery.com/has/)

[:eq()](https://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)

Comment: Thank you empiric. This is a very simple yet effective answer which solves my problem. I would still like to understand the application of closest in these scenarios but I will investigate further with other tests.

Comment: @shifty_uk the issue with your code is that `boxFilters` only has a reference to all matched elements. The `if` construct will not change the reference to the element which contains at least 8 children. So it always applies the class to all `ol`